# Joining 2 unequal sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 select queries that I want to join into one with no duplicates. Also I will like to join them using their primary key of shiftindex found in all the tables. how do I do this?

**The first select statement is:**

```
SELECT     dbo.hist_exproot.year, 
           dbo.hist_exproot.[month#], 
           dbo.hist_exproot.month, 
           dbo.hist_exproot.day, 
           dbo.hist_exproot.[shift#], 
           dbo.hist_exproot.shift, 
           dbo.hist_loads.excav, 
           SUM(dbo.hist_loads.loadtons) AS 'TONS', 
           SUM(dbo.hist_loads.ex_tmcat00)/3600 AS 'TTOTAL', 
           SUM(dbo.hist_loads.ex_tmcat01+dbo.hist_loads.ex_tmcat02)/3600 AS 'T_EFECT'
FROM       dbo.hist_exproot 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_loads 
           ON dbo.hist_exproot.shiftindex = dbo.hist_loads.shiftindex
WHERE     (dbo.hist_exproot.year >= 16)
GROUP BY  dbo.hist_exproot.year, 
          dbo.hist_exproot.[month#], 
          dbo.hist_exproot.month, 
          dbo.hist_exproot.day, 
          dbo.hist_exproot.[shift#], 
          dbo.hist_exproot.shift, 
          dbo.hist_loads.excav
```

**The second is:**

```
SELECT     dbo.hist_exproot.year,
           dbo.hist_exproot.[month#], 
           dbo.hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
           dbo.hist_exproot.shift, 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
           dbo.hist_exproot.crew, 
           dbo.hist_reasontable.category, 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.reason, 
           dbo.hist_reasontable.name, 
           dbo.hist_operlist.operid, 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.starttime, 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.endtime, 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.duration/3600 as 'Time', 
           dbo.hist_statusevents.comment
FROM       dbo.hist_reasontable 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_statusevents 
           ON dbo.hist_reasontable.shiftindex = dbo.hist_statusevents.shiftindex 
           AND dbo.hist_reasontable.reason = dbo.hist_statusevents.reason 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_operlist 
           ON dbo.hist_statusevents.operid = dbo.hist_operlist.operid 
           AND dbo.hist_statusevents.shiftindex = dbo.hist_operlist.shiftindex 
           AND dbo.hist_reasontable.shiftindex = dbo.hist_operlist.shiftindex 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_exproot 
           ON dbo.hist_statusevents.shiftindex = dbo.hist_exproot.shiftindex
WHERE      
           (dbo.hist_exproot.year >= 16) 
            AND (dbo.hist_statusevents.unit = 2) 
            AND(dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt <> 'L98') 
            AND (dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt <> 'L96')
            AND  (dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt <> 'L09')
            AND (dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt <> 'S47')
ORDER BY dbo.hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
         dbo.hist_statusevents.eqmt
```

Please let me know if you have questions.

Thank you

Comment: Unless you're actually using MySQL somehow, the `mysql` tag probably doesn't apply and should be removed.

Comment: You desperately need to use aliases. This query is nightmare to read.

Comment: Assuming this is indeed T-SQL, CTEs are your friend, no matter how unreadable the query. `WITH T1 AS (SELECT ...), T2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON ...`. The `ORDER BY` clauses in the subqueries need to go, though.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what you are asking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (Query 1) JOIN
(Query 2) ON...
```

The join of these two subqueries will be handled by what you put after the on and the distinct will eliminate all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT an answer but is entirely too long for a comment. Here is what your queries would look like if you were using aliases. I cleaned up some of the other formatting as well so you can see what this should look like.

```
SELECT he.year
    , he.[month#]
    , he.month
    , he.day
    , he.[shift#]
    , he.shift
    , hl.excav
    , SUM(hl.loadtons) AS 'TONS'
    , SUM(hl.ex_tmcat00)/3600 AS 'TTOTAL'
    , SUM(hl.ex_tmcat01+hl.ex_tmcat02)/3600 AS 'T_EFECT'
FROM dbo.hist_exproot he
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_loads hl ON he.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex
WHERE he.year >= 16
GROUP BY he.year
    , he.[month#]
    , he.MONTH
    , he.DAY
    , he.[shift#]
    , he.shift
    , hl.excav



SELECT er.year
    , er.[month#]
    , er.shiftdate
    , er.shift
    , se.eqmt
    , er.crew
    , rt.category
    , se.reason
    , rt.name
    , ol.operid
    , se.starttime
    , se.endtime
    , se.duration/3600 as 'Time'
    , se.comment
FROM dbo.hist_reasontable rt
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_statusevents se ON rt.shiftindex = se.shiftindex 
            AND rt.reason = se.reason 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_operlist ol ON se.operid = ol.operid 
            AND se.shiftindex = ol.shiftindex 
            AND rt.shiftindex = ol.shiftindex 
INNER JOIN dbo.hist_exproot er ON se.shiftindex = er.shiftindex
WHERE er.year >= 16
    AND se.unit = 2
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L98'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L96'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L09'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'S47'
ORDER BY er.shiftdate
    , se.eqmt
```

Comment: Lol I edited the question as is. Look I went cross eyes with the code syntax and styling bit. Never mind understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server.

As others have pointed out, one way is to use CTEs like `SELECT DISTINCT column_list FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN CTE2 ON join_condition` with CTE1 and CTE2 being the original queries without the `ORDER BY` clause. The join column based on your example would be `dbo.hist_exproot.shiftindex`.

Another way is to join all tables as follows...

```
SELECT 
    he.year
    , he.[month#]
    , he.month
    , he.day
    , he.[shift#]
    , he.shift
    , hl.excav
    , SUM(hl.loadtons) AS 'TONS'
    , SUM(hl.ex_tmcat00)/3600 AS 'TTOTAL'
    , SUM(hl.ex_tmcat01+hl.ex_tmcat02)/3600 AS 'T_EFECT'
    , he.shiftdate
    , se.eqmt
    , he.crew
    , rt.category
    , se.reason
    , rt.name
    , ol.operid
    , se.starttime
    , se.endtime
    , se.duration/3600 as 'Time'
    , se.comment
FROM 
    dbo.hist_exproot he
    INNER JOIN dbo.hist_loads hl ON he.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex
    INNER JOIN dbo.hist_statusevents se ON se.shiftindex = he.shiftindex
    INNER JOIN dbo.hist_reasontable rt ON rt.shiftindex = se.shiftindex 
                                          AND rt.reason = se.reason
    INNER JOIN dbo.hist_operlist ol ON se.operid = ol.operid 
                                       AND se.shiftindex = ol.shiftindex 
                                       AND rt.shiftindex = ol.shiftindex 
WHERE 
    he.year >= 16
    AND se.unit = 2
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L98'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L96'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'L09'
    AND se.eqmt <> 'S47'
GROUP BY 
    he.year
    , he.[month#]
    , he.MONTH
    , he.DAY
    , he.[shift#]
    , he.shift
    , hl.excav
ORDER BY 
    he.shiftdate
    , se.eqmt
```

Use a `DISTINCT` clause if you want to eliminate any possible duplicates from the resultset. But it's good to avoid if you don't need it.

The second solution joining all the tables results in a more complex query and might not have the best query plan. I would try both approaches and use the one that is more efficient.

Thanks to Sean Lange for reformatting the original queries.